# How to select specific columns dynamically in a REST API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to develop a REST API using Java and Spring boot. I have an entity class User.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private Date createdDate;
}
```

My requirement is to select some specific fields from this entity. These fields can be specified
dynamically in REST API url like
http://localhost:8080/getUserDetails?start=2021-01-01&end=2021-05-05&fields=firstName
http://localhost:8080/getUserDetails?start=2021-01-01&end=2021-05-05&fields=firstName,lastName

When fields=firstName , I want to return only firstName in JSON.
Similary, firstName and lastName in JSON when fields = firstName,lastName.

If i use criteria query `query.select(root.get("firstName"),root.get("lastName"))`
than i have to create constructors in Entity / POJO class.
There can only be one constructor with 2 String parameters. So this approach will fail when i need to select mobileNumber and email.

If i use spring Projections than i am not able to get how to select dynamic fields in Projections without adding projections = "some value" in rest endpoint url. Also if i use interface or class projections i will have to define required fields there. Fields should be dynamic in my case.

Also i am trying to avoid fetching of all columns and than filtering it out based on requested fields as it is inefficient.

So can anyone please help me out?

Comment: In this case I think REST will require way too much boilerplate, have a look into GraphQL,
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-graphql